# Vue2.js - Call a method inside a object and callback (this issue)

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

### Context

I'm using `Vue2.js`to implement pickerOptions to preselect dateRange. I created a function `createDate` that does what it sounds. The `DatePicker` component comes from [here](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/date-picker)

### Issue

I don't know the right way to call the function `createdDate` within the object `pickerOptions` and within the callback function `onClick(picker)`

When I do so I got this error `Uncaught TypeError: this.createdDate is not a function`. This makes sense since `this` reffers to

```
Object {__ob__: Observer}
onClick:function onClick(picker)
text:"Last week"
```

What should I do to be able to access my function `createDate` or how to call it ?

```
export default {
         name: 'app',
         data() {
             return {
                 private: {
                     pickerOptions: {
                         shortcuts: [{
                             text: 'Last week',
                             onClick(picker) {
                                 const end = new Date();
                                 const start = this.createDate(-7);
                                 picker.$emit('pick', [start, end]);
                             }
                         }]
                     }
                 }
             }
         },
         methods: {
             createDate(days, months, years) {
                 let date = new Date();
                 date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
                 date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + months);
                 date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() + years);
                 return date;
             },
         }
     };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grabbing a reference in the data function should let you use it further down. Try this

```
data() { 
    let self = this;
    return { 
     .... 
       const start = self.$options.methods.createDate(-7);
    }
}
```

Comment: This did it : `self.$options.methods.createDate`. You can update your answer. Thank you !